# Kafka consumer problem while saving consumed data to GCP bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, bucket

I am using a a consumer to get data from Kafka topic then store that data in a GCP bucket in 1 minute intervals.
Here's the code for the Kafka consumer.

```
import os
import kafka
import json
from datetime import date
from io import BytesIO
from google.cloud import storage
import time

storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/XXXX.json"
)
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("XXXX")


def get_filname(topic):
    return bucket.blob(topic + "_" + str(date.today()))


def retrieve_data_from_topic(topic, topic_name):
    data = []
    existing_data = []
    begin_time = time.time()
    blob = get_filname(topic_name)
    if not blob.exists():
        store_to_bucket(blob, [])
    for message in topic:
        blob = get_filname(topic_name)
        data.append(message.value)
        file_data = blob.download_as_text()
        existing_data = list(json.loads(file_data))
        new_data = []
        interval = 60  ## 1 min
        for fresh_d in data:
            if fresh_d not in existing_data:
                existing_data.append(fresh_d)
        current_time = time.time()
        period = current_time - begin_time
        if period >= interval:
            store_to_bucket(blob, existing_data)
            begin_time = current_time
            topic.commit()


def store_to_bucket(blob, msg):
    blob.upload_from_string(
        data=json.dumps(msg),
    )


def retrieve_topic(topic: str):
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(
        topic,
        bootstrap_servers=["kafka:9093", "kafka:9092"],
        value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode("utf-8")),
        group_id="metaowl-bucket" + topic,
        auto_offset_reset="earliest",
        max_poll_records=300,
        max_poll_interval_ms= 14400000,
        enable_auto_commit=False,
    )
    return consumer


def topic_list():
    consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(
        value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode("utf-8")),
        group_id="metaowl-bucket-list",
        auto_offset_reset="earliest",
        enable_auto_commit=True,
        bootstrap_servers=["kafka:9093", "kafka:9092"],
    )
    tokens = set()
    for topic in consumer.topics():
        tokens.add(topic.split("_")[0])
    return tokens
```

The problem i am facing is that the consumer takes too long to process messages and sometimes exceeds the limit of 4 hours that i set with max_poll_interval_ms which causes the consumer groupID to rebalance and fail since i am using only one consumer groupID.
If someone with enough experience can point out the why this problem is happening.

i tried changing max_poll_records value and max_poll_interval_ms but it doesnt make sense since my messages are not long enough to require a long processing time

Comment: Unclear what part of your code "takes too long". Have you tried adding any logging to see where the slowness occurs? Also, what happens in your loop when you don't have 60 seconds worth of data? In other words, you seem to not be writing to your bucket unless you are guaranteed to have data in the topic... You should break your consumer loop when you reach the very end of the topic and write the data that's available. Otherwise, for a slow producer (one message every 2 minutes, for example), you'll probably be missing those values

Comment: By the way, Kafka Connect already has a GCS Sink that supports time based partitioning

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but i already switched to using airflow to consume data from kafka and then load it to buckets which works rather smoothly. concerning Kafka connect feature in GCS sink, isnt it expensive to implement ?

Comment: No more expensive than running Airflow. Kafka Connect doesn't need a database server like Airflow does